# Get node that cursor is in

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am showing the XML data in a text area and I want to get the node that cursor is in.

Is there a method or a way that I can use to get the absolute position based on the cursor location?

Here is the basic XML:

```
<root> 
  <branch>
      <leaf/>
      <leaf/>
      <leaf name="Carol"/>
  </branch>
  <branch>
      <leaf/>
      <leaf/>
      <branch>
          <leaf name="Bill"/>
          <leaf/>
      </branch>
  </branch>
</root>
```

So if I have the cursor in node named "Bill" I want it to return a [1,2,0]. So the values are indexes the children nodes at each nested level. So if the cursor was in the leaf node named "Bill" the value would be [1,2,0] which means, second item, then third item, then first item. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `getLineIndexAtPoint` ot [TextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html), read it's content and then search it in the xml to get the "array" indexes.